# EntityFramework Code First, is it possible to map this

Tags: ef-code-first

is there even a possibility to map this to one entity ?

```
select x,y,z, (select count(*) from othertable where tableid=table.id) as othertablecount
from table t
```

i want to map this to a class that looks like this:

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string z { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should map it properly as a collection and use a projection for querying:

```
class Stuff
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<OtherStuff> { get; set; }
}

var stuffWithCount = from stuff in myContext.Stuff
                     select new
                            {
                                stuff.x, ...
                                count = stuff.OtherStuff.Count()
                            };
```